# How to get the keys from array

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

I am using **GCM(Google could messaging)** for the very first time and i am stuck with some problem. Although the problem has nothing to do with the GCM.I have a JSON data

```
$data='{"multicast_id":7917175795873320166,"success":6,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":4,

"results":[

{"registration_id":"3","message_id":"m1"},
{"message_id":"m1"},
{"message_id":"m1"},
{"registration_id":"3","message_id":"m1"},

{"registration_id":"3","message_id":"m1"},

{"registration_id":"3","message_id":"m1"}]}';

$newData=json_decode($data);
```

Now what i want is the keys in the **result** array for which **registration_id** is set but i am unable to do so.
I can access the **registration_Id** like `$newData->results[0]->registration_id`

I have found that **array_keys()** returns the keys in an array but how can i get the keys in the `$newData->results` array for which `$newData->results[$index]->registration_id` is set?
The major issue is that i **cant use the foreach loop** for doing it. Hope i will get some help here.

Comment: why you cant use a foreach loop?

Comment: Because i can do it easily with a foreach loop. But i wan to know if i can achieve it with any inbuilt function also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. First off, use the second param of [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/json_decode) so you're actually working with an array and not an object. Then [filter the array](https://www.php.net/array_filter) with the items you want (where `registration_id` is set) and [get the keys](https://www.php.net/array_keys).

```
$newData=json_decode($data, true);

$filteredResults = array_filter($newData['results'], function($item) {
    return isset($item['registration_id']);
});

print_r(array_keys($filteredResults));
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/e8doL

Note this code assumes you are using PHP 5.3 or later. If you are on an earlier version, you'll need to define your `array_filter` callback function first and pass it in rather than using an anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i was unaware of the bo0lean parameter in json_decode(). Thanks for letting me know about it.

Comment: @Letmesee Sure thing. So does this provide what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes absolutely. I will mark it as an answer as soon as i will be be able to do so. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you can only address the items in object mode, is due to the way the json_decode was called.

To return $data as an associative array, use:

```
$newData=json_decode($data, true)
```

Comment: This doesn't address the original question: `how can i get the keys in the $newData->results array for which $newData->results[$index]->registration_id is set? `.

Answer (score 1):

```
$newData=json_decode($data, true)
```

if you're passing the second param `true` then it converts the json to `assosiative array`(an array with key val pair).[Official doc](https://www.php.net/json_decode)
Here is official documentation [Json_decode Php Official](https://www.php.net/json_decode)

an example to show that

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

its output will be

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```